# Why does SwiftUI Progress View disappear after toggling Boolean value?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In the following code, either a SwiftUI ProgressView or a Text view displaying "false" should be drawn. This initially works the first time isLoading is toggled on. However, on subsequent toggles nothing is drawn when isLoading is true. Is this a Bug? And if it is, is there a known workaround?

```
struct TestProgressView: View {
    @State var isLoading: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Section {
            Button {
                isLoading.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Toggle Stuff")
            }

            if isLoading {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                Text(isLoading.description)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not reproducible on iOS 16.1 built with Xcode 14.1 for me

Comment: @jnpdx Thank you - I’ll have to double check what version I am testing on, as I thought I was on the same. I’ll take a look later today.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
@AppStorage var isLoading: Bool
```

the State is persistent in the user defaults and it should have the correct value. With @State the variable is reinitialized always with false every time you call it.